# How to read URL which stored in a data-src of a image and set that URL in src of another img controller onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing website by using ASP.net. In there in a page I am generating img controls by using this code for an image gallery.

```
  foreach (string url in listImageUrl)
            {
                LiteralControl lit = new LiteralControl();
                lit.Text = String.Format("<img src='/Images/Thumbnail/{0}' data-url='/Images/Full/{0}' id='imgThumbnail' onclick='loadFullImage(this)'/>", url);

                pnlThumbnailImage.Controls.Add(lit);
            }
```

Then I am adding pnlThumbnailImage to placeholder in my page.

Also there is an another img controll in page. It goes like this.

```
<img id="imgFull" src="" />
```

What I want to do is when an user click above thumbnail images the Full image path which stored in "data-url=" should be apply to src of the imgFull control(another img controller).

So how to do that in javascript?

I wrote this javascript function.
But it didn't work.

```
function loadFullImage(ctrl)
{
    var image = document.getElementById(ctrl);

    var imgFull = document.getElementById("imgFull");
    imgFull.src = image.getAttribute("data-url");

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ctrl` parameter inside the `loadFullImage()` function is not the id of the image element but the HTML DOM element that was clicked on itself. Therefore, your code should be like this:

```
function loadFullImage(ctrl)
{
    var url = ctrl.getAttribute('data-url');

    var imgFull = document.getElementById("imgFull");
    imgFull.src = url;

}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of what you subtlety changed would be helpful.

Comment: The OP thought `ctrl` was the element ID. Your code implies that `ctrl` (you named `object`) is actually the element itself. Pointing that fact out would make it easier and more clear why your answer is correct.

Comment: You are right, should have mentioned it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Also, code-only answers frequently show up in the [low quality answer queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276622/369450) to be reviewed. If a reviewer is not careful, they may not realize the difference between your code and the code posted by the OP, and then recommend that it be deleted.